# c# Cefsharp - javax.servlet.ServletException

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I'm trying to load an URL in a ChromiumWebBrowser, but it throws the following error:

javax.servlet.ServletException: Can't find bundle for base name es.iecisa.portability.i18n.messages, locale en_US

java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name es.iecisa.portability.i18n.messages, locale en_US

[HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEjHf.png)

Here's my code:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Cef.EnableHighDPISupport();
        var settings = new CefSettings();
        settings.IgnoreCertificateErrors = true;
        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("ignore-certificate-errors", string.Empty);
        settings.CachePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "CefSharp\\Cache");
        Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: true, browserProcessHandler: null);

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new FrmMain());
    }

    private void FramMain_Load()
    {
        browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(templateC.HomeUrl);
        browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        BrowserSettings settings = new BrowserSettings();
        settings.Javascript = CefState.Enabled;
        settings.Plugins = CefState.Enabled;
        settings.WebSecurity = CefState.Disabled;
        browser.BrowserSettings = settings;

        pnlBrowser.Controls.Add(browser);
    }
```

Comment: Does your website load in `Chrome` when using `en-US` locale? `CefSettings.Locale`